# Jquery focusout event triggerd twice on input text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-focusout

i'm working on a web application in mvc and generated textbox with loop so the id of every textbox in unique and on the focusout event of every textbox check the validation through ajax. The problem is focusout event is triggered twice automatically and show twice value of every textbox and pass twice value, i d'ont know what the reason. My code is  given  below.
Highly Thankful to all of you!

```
$('#StartTime0').focusout(function () {
                if ($(this).val() && $('#EndTime0').val()) {
                    var MonTime1 = checkTime($(this).val(), $("#EndTime0").val())
                    if (MonTime1) {
                        $("#Onelimit0").addClass("hidden");
                        console.log($(this).val());
                        console.log($('#EndTime0').val());
                        //DoctorTimeCheck($(this).val(), $("#EndTime0").val())                        
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#Onelimit0").removeClass("hidden");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $("#Onelimit0").addClass("hidden");
                }
            });
```

Comment: When is the binding created?

Comment: If you mistakenly call $('#StartTime0').focusout() twice, the event handler will be called twice.

Comment: @TakashiHarano the second one is using after form submit to hide required error but i already checked this after commenting that but still failled!

Comment: @Taplar at document ready.

Comment: So it's not in a function that's being repeated called, or in a loop of some kind or anything?

Comment: @Taplar No, it's not! but due to scenario the focusout event trigger multiple time...